# Bootstrap - Align several forms vertically

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have several forms in one page, with only one label, one input and one submit each time.
How can I align labels vertically, input and submit without using `col-md`?

```
<form class="form-inline" action="action1.php" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="input1">Email test</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="Email" name="email">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit 1</button>
</form>

<form class="form-inline" action="action2.php" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="input2">Email</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input2" placeholder="Email" name="email">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit 2</button>
</form>
...
...
```

See:

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/Lwss0606/

Comment: what do you mean by align? align vertically ? align horizontaly? what exactly you want to do?

Comment: what do mean by Align?

Comment: Witch align you want ?
Show more code or jsfiddle to clarify the question.

Comment: Align verticaly.
I've juste added a screen

Comment: We don't understand what you want aligned vertical,

Answer (score 0):

As per the `UI` image you have posted. Use `col-md-x` class to provide grid structure to your forms elements. For example

```
   <form class="form-inline" action="action1.php" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="input1" class="col-md-3">Email test</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-6" id="input1" placeholder="Email" name="email">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default col-md-3">Submit 1</button>
            </div>

        </form>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sq9Xy/46/)

Comment: I hoped there's a solution without col-md in fact. But I finaly used it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can try this style

```
.form-inline input{
  width: 60%;
float: left;
margin-right: 5px;
}
.form-inline label {
  float: left;
padding-right: 10px;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
height: 34px;
}
```